# Type in haskell explanation of IO

Tags: haskell

Can any one help me with understanding this function type?
`stateOfMind :: BotBrain -> IO (Phrase -> Phrase)`

`stateOfMind` is a function and `BotBrain` is just a type.

```
type Phrase = [String]
type PhrasePair = (Phrase, Phrase)
type BotBrain = [(Phrase, [Phrase])]
```

If `stateOfMind` had this type: `BotBrain -> (Phrase -> Phrase)`, then
`stateOfMind` would take a `BotBrain` as an argument to produce a new function that takes a `Phrase` and gives a `Phrase` as a result. 
But now we have an `IO`, i.e.  `IO (Phrase -> Phrase)`.
What does that mean?

`randomIO` has monadic type but why is to like that? Is is because of the seed we choose?
Monadic I normally used for input and output, but a random generator actually doesn't get any input from user at run time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random number in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594655/random-number-in-haskell)

Answer (score 2):

```
stateOfMind :: BotBrain -> IO (Phrase -> Phrase)
```

`stateOfMind` takes a `BotBrain` and returns an `IO` action whose result is a function from `Phrase` to `Phrase`. When you execute an `IO (Phrase -> Phrase)` action in the `IO` monad, you get an ordinary pure function `Phrase -> Phrase`.

`randomIO` is in `IO` because it uses `getStdRandom` to change the state of the global standard random number generator. Multiple calls to `randomIO` can (and will) return different results, which is precisely what `IO` indicates.

You can create a pure generator with `mkStdGen` and get values from it purely:

```
let
  g1 = mkStdGen 42      -- Seed value
  (r1, g2) = random g1  -- Get first random number
  (r2, g3) = random g2  -- Get second random number
in r1 + r2
```

And a convenient way to get rid of the repetition here is to use the `State` monad:

```
flip evalState (mkStdGen 42) $ do
  r1 <- state random
  r2 <- state random
  return (r1 + r2)
```