# Random Function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, functional-programming

I'm currently working on a program in Haskell (which I am very new to) where I need to randomly generate co-ordinates and use them around the program in several places, however, I don't want to be threading IO around the whole program, nor the seed. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594655/random-number-in-haskell) link where they use `num <- randomIO :: IO Float` however I keep getting - `` Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]' Expected type: [Float] ``. I in theory need the co-ordinates to be integer values, so if there is a better way of doing it that would be great! The full stack is below:

```
Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'
      Expected type: [Float]
        Actual type: IO Float
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: y <- randomIO :: IO Float
```

An example of the code that is causing an error.

```
import Data.List
import System.Random

someF :: [[Char]]
someF = do
            ytemp <- randomIO :: IO Float
            []
```

Comment: You _can't_ generate random numbers without treading either `IO` (or a more specialised monad) or seeds through the program, for [quite fundamental reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). One thing you could do is generate an infinite list of random numbers up front, and then just consume that – but this is in practice hardly different from passing around a `Gen`, except the latter gives you more flexibility. Really, the best option is to use a monad. Not necessarily `IO` but [`RVar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.7.7/docs/Data-Random.html#t:RVar).

Comment: do explore [tag:do-notation] in case you're not well versed in it. you do not show the [mcve] here, but it looks like your `do` block's type  is `[] a` but `randomIO :: IO a`, and `[]` is not `IO`. the Monad must be the same, all throughout a given `do` block.

Comment: @WillNess I've added a minimum reproducible example! :)

Comment: Your example does not produce an error message like the one you posted.

Comment: @leftaroundabout sorry about that, I've updated the example! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
someF :: [[Char]]
someF = do { ... }
```

Here you have `do` block, but it's not in an `IO` action. That in itself is actually ok: `do` blocks can be in other types but `IO`, but they need be in a *monadic* type. It so happens that lists are also monadic, i.e. the compiler treats this as

```
someF :: [] [Char]
someF = do { ... }
```

(where `[]` is *not* the empty list, but the type-level constructor for list-types).

...This is analogous to

```
someF :: IO [Char]
someF = do { ... }
```

in which case you *could* have `ytemp <- randomIO` in the `do` block. Conversely, in a list-monad `do` block you could have, for instance,

```
  ytemp <- [1, 2, 5.3] :: [Float]
```

So this is why you get that error message: the compiler requires something of type `[...]`, IOW `[] (...)`, but you give it something of type `IO (...)` instead.

If you need to generate random values in the middle of your code, then you *must* have a suitable monad around (or explicitly passed seeds).

```
someF :: IO [[Char]]
someF = do
    ytemp <- randomIO :: IO Float
    return []
```